# Javascript: something like PHP file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
    //simply api
    if(isset($_POST["submitmail"])){
        if(strlen($_POST["mail"]) >= 5){
            $api = file_get_contents("API_LINK");

            if($api == "good"){
                echo "<script>alert('Thanks');</script>";    
            }
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('Try again');</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

That's my very simple api, kind of. I'd like to somehow convert this into JS. The PHP code will activate the URL, and on the API_LINK I'll store the data from the url.

The very same with JS or a similar solution would be perfect.

Comment: Are you asking if you can get the contents of a file with JS, without reloading the page? Have you heard of AJAX?

Comment: If you are looking for other than AJAX,try this `http://locutus.io/php/filesystem/file_get_contents/`